# How to print two arrays side by side with bash script?

Tags: arrays, bash, printing, awk, echo

I couldn't find a good and simple answer to this question neither on google nor here on stackoverflow.

Basically I have two arrays that I need to print into the terminal side by side since one array is a list of terms and the other the terms's definitions. Does anyone know a good way of doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use an associative array?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a C-style for loop to accomplish this, assuming both arrays are the same length:

```
for ((i=0; i<=${#arr1[@]}; i++)); do
    printf '%s %s\n' "${arr1[i]}" "${arr2[i]}"
done
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to loop through array indices? Like `i in "${!arr1[@]}"`?

Comment: @oguzismail yes, and it would better handle sparse arrays

Answer (score 13):

Here's a "one-liner":

```
paste <(printf "%s\n" "${terms[@]}") <(printf "%s\n" "${defs[@]}")
```

This will create lines consisting of a term and a def separated by a tab, which might not, strictly speaking, be "side by side" (since they're not really in columns). If you knew how wide the first column should be, you could use something like:

```
paste -d' ' <(printf "%-12.12s\n" "${terms[@]}") <(printf "%s\n" "${defs[@]}")
```

which will pad or truncate the terms to 12 characters exactly, and then put a space between the two columns instead of a tab (`-d' '`).

Comment: For those who use shell in POSIX mode: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151911/syntax-error-near-unexpected-token

Comment: And pure Bash way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32998279/3393574