# Defining a variable from a value in a JSON array in Bash

Tags: arrays, json, bash

The US Naval Observatory has an API that outputs a JSON file containing the sunrise and sunset times, among other things, as documented [here](http://aa.usno.navy.mil/data/docs/api.php).

[Here is an example](http://api.usno.navy.mil/rstt/oneday?ID=iOnTheSk&date=today&tz=0&coords=30,130) of the output JSON file:

```
{
"error":false,
"apiversion":"2.0.0",
"year":2017,
"month":6,
"day":10,
"dayofweek":"Saturday",
"datechanged":false,
"lon":130.000000,
"lat":30.000000,
"tz":0,

"sundata":[
            {"phen":"U", "time":"03:19"},
            {"phen":"S", "time":"10:21"},
            {"phen":"EC", "time":"10:48"},
            {"phen":"BC", "time":"19:51"},
            {"phen":"R", "time":"20:18"}],

"moondata":[
            {"phen":"R", "time":"10:49"},
            {"phen":"U", "time":"16:13"},
            {"phen":"S", "time":"21:36"}],

"prevsundata":[
            {"phen":"BC","time":"19:51"},
            {"phen":"R","time":"20:18"}],

"closestphase":{"phase":"Full Moon","date":"June 9, 2017","time":"13:09"},
"fracillum":"99%",
"curphase":"Waning Gibbous"
}
```

I'm relatively new to using JSON, but I understand that everything in square brackets after "sundata" is a JSON array (please correct me if I'm wrong). So I searched for instructions on how to get a value from a JSON array, without success.

I have downloaded the file to my system using:

```
wget -O usno.json "http://api.usno.navy.mil/rstt/oneday?ID=iOnTheSk&date=today&tz=0&coords=30,130"
```

I need to extract the time (in HH:MM format) from this line:

```
    {"phen":"S", "time":"10:21"},
```

...and then use it to create a variable (that I will later write to a separate file).

I would prefer to use Bash if possible, preferably using a JSON parser (such as *jq*) if it'll be easier to understand/implement. I'd rather not use Python (which was suggested by a lot of the articles I have read previously) if possible as I am trying to become more familiar with Bash specifically.

I have examined a lot of different webpages, including answers on Stack Overflow, but none of them have specifically covered an array line with two key/value pairs per line (they've only explained how to do it with only one pair per line, which isn't what the above file structure has, sadly).

Specifically, I have read these articles, but they did not solve my particular problem:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177843/parse-one-field-from-an-json-array-into-bash-array
- [Parsing JSON with Unix tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955505/parsing-json-with-unix-tools)
- [Parse json array in shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39227191/parse-json-array-in-shell-script)
- [Parse JSON to array in a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38364261/parse-json-to-array-in-a-shell-script)
- [What is JSON and why would I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383692/what-is-json-and-why-would-i-use-it)
- https://developers.squarespace.com/what-is-json/
- [Read the json data in shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20488315/read-the-json-data-in-shell-script)

Thanks in advance for any thoughts.

Side note: I have managed to do this with a complex 150-odd line script made up of "sed"s, "grep"s, "awk"s, and whatnot, but obviously if there's a one-liner JSON-native solution that's more elegant, I'd prefer to use that as I need to minimise power usage wherever possible (it's being run on a battery-powered device).
(Side-note to the side-note: the script was so long because I need to do it for each line in the JSON file, not just the "S" value)

Comment: You don't want to parse JSON (or most formats with nested structures for that matter) as a plain text or with regex. Save yourself a lot of trouble and get [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

Comment: @zwer, I have jq, as suggested by the articles in the links toward the end of my question. Your answer doesn't help me solve the problem. Could you give specifics on how to actually use it for this purpose please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you already have [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) you can easily select your desired time with:

```
sun_time=$(jq '.sundata[] | select(.phen == "S").time' usno.json)
echo $sun_time
# "10:21"
```

Comment: Fantastic; that worked perfectly. Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you must use "regular" bash commands (really, use `jq`):

```
wget -O - "http://api.usno.navy.mil/rstt/oneday?ID=iOnTheSk&date=today&tz=0&coords=30,130" \
    | sed -n '/^"sundata":/,/}],$/p' \
    | sed -n -e '/"phen":"S"/{s/^.*"time":"//'\;s/...$//\;p}
```

Example:

```
$ wget -O - "http://api.usno.navy.mil/rstt/oneday?ID=iOnTheSk&date=today&tz=0&coords=30,130" | sed -n '/^"sundata":/,/}],$/p' | sed -n -e '/"phen":"S"/{s/^.*"time":"//'\;s/...$//\;p} 
--2017-06-10 08:02:46--  http://api.usno.navy.mil/rstt/oneday?ID=iOnTheSk&date=today&tz=0&coords=30,130
Resolving api.usno.navy.mil (api.usno.navy.mil)... 199.211.133.93
Connecting to api.usno.navy.mil (api.usno.navy.mil)|199.211.133.93|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [application/json]
Saving to: ‘STDOUT’

-                            [ <=>                              ]     753  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2017-06-10 08:02:47 (42.6 MB/s) - written to stdout [753]

10:21
```